# one function used to change variable in another function

Tags: python-3.x, function, calendar, variable-assignment

I am trying to teach myself python, so I have made a project a few smaller projects working together and one of them is a Date tracker. The Date function works. However, when I try to call the new day function to bump the day by 1 and change month and year if needed, I get an error:

```
"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'day'".
```

I understand that inside a function is a separate local variable not a global and that your not supposed to make global variables constantly changing. So I'm trying to get one function to call and use another's variable I plan on making it into a button that changes the day by 1 or 7, I'm just having trouble visualizing how to get the function working. Any direction or help with getting this to work would be greatly appreciated

```
# making a basic calendar
#list of months and their days
month_day = [[1,'January',31],[2,'February',28],
[3,'March',31],[4,'April',30],
[5,'May',31],[6,'June',30],
[7,'July',31],[8,'August',31],
[9,'September',30],[10,'October',31],
[11,'November',30],[12,'December',31]]
#checksum for new year
def isleapyear(year):
    if year%4 == 0:
        if year%100 == 0:
            if year%400 == 0:
                month_day[1][2] = 29
            else:
                month_day[1][2] = 28
        else :
            month_day[1][2] = 29
    else:
        month_day[1][2] = 28
#editable date (supposed to be
def Date():
    year = 1
    day = 31
    month = 1
    isleapyear(year)
    date = [day, month_day[month-1][1], year]
    return date
#function to increase day counter by 1
def new_day():
    #checksum for month or year rollover
    if Date.day == month_day[Date.month-1][2]:
        Date.day = 1
        if Date.month == 12:
            Date.month = 1
            Date.year = Date.year + 1
        else:
            Date.month = month + 1
    else:
        Date.day = Date.day + 1

new_day()
print (Date())
```

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't get variables from function.

One way you can deal with it is in function `Date` add line `global year, day, month`, this will make variables year, day, month global so you can use it in all function and outside of functions. And in `new_day` remove `Date.`.

This should get rid of your problem.

`Date.day` would only work if `Date` was class not function.

For example:

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self):
        self.year = 1
        self.day = 31
        self.month = 1

Date().year # Should return 1
Date().day # Should return 31
Date().month # Should return 1
```

[Edit]

If you want to change year, day or month

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self):
        self.year = 1
        self.day = 31
        self.month = 1

    def change_year(self, to):
        self.year = to

    def change_day(self, to):
        self.day = to

    def change_month(self, to):
        self.month = to


Date().year # Should return 1
Date().day # Should return 31
Date().month # Should return 1

example = Date()
example.year # Returns 1
example.change_year(3)
example.year # Returns 3
```

But best way to make variable is to use `global`.

Example

```
def main():
    global time
    time = 10

main()

print(time) # Prints 10
```

global statement make a variable in function 'global', in other words variable will act like it was outside of function.

Comment: so a class will make it a universal argument that can be accessed by everything?

Comment: Well, it's more complicated like that, `Date.year` will return always 1, so you can't change it. If you want to change it you would need to make another function inside class.

Comment: Thank you! ill put it in as a global it seems like it will be less of a headache. I would give you a upvote for a helpful comment but apparently since i just made an account to ask this question i cant vote on a response yet sorry.